# im trying an api call but nothing is showing up and i'm receiving this error as shown in the image, can anyone spot where im going wrong?

Tags: react-native

[Image of code and targeted api information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM0s7.jpg)

im trying an api call but nothing is shooing up and i'm receiving this error as shown in the image, can anyone help?

Comment: You are not destructuring the object correctly. I would suggest to get it working without using restructuring, get what you need from the data object first.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: Instead of the image you attached you should paste the structure of the response as text and specify which parts of the data you need. Then it would be easier to answer your question as currently it's not clear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: i tried screenshotting it and sending it but it does not let me reply an image, i need everything until the 2nd line after the midnight object